# Suppress systemd: "Directory to mount over is not empty, mounting anyway."

Tags: mount, systemd, logs

I am purposefully mounting a read-write copy of a directory on top of the read-only version of itself.

This generates a log message such as:

```
Aug 27 14:31:02 svelte systemd[1]: mnt-btrfs\x2dvol-rootfs.mount: Directory /mnt/btrfs-vol/rootfs to mount over is not empty, mounting anyway.
```

Is there any way to supress this message to reduce log noise?

Comment: For what reason do you want to suppress this warning. You know, it's a warning for a reason. It seems you use btrfs filesystem, do you have heard about btrfs snaps?

Comment: It might also help if you explained the actual reason you have for doing so rather than, say, using the `remount` option.

Answer (score 0):

Your mount could always redirect stout or stderr to `/dev/null`, what about that?

There's a `-q` flag for `mount.btrfs` but it:

> Print only error or warning messages. Options --features or --help are unaffected.

According to the man page, so I'd expect it will still give you the warning.

Comment: Wouldn't work as this comes from processing `/etc/mtab` and would hide useful warnings.

Comment: @TomHale Then it sounds like you're stuck with the warning. You could try the quiet flag on the mount, but I expect it wont help.

Comment: Given it's not mount issuing the warning, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure preciously what logging level this particular message is, however you could modify `MaxLevelConsole=` or `MaxLevelStore=` within `journald.conf` to potentially suppress these messages (of course this would also suppress other messages of the same level, which may be a double-edged sword if you do this to anything excluding `MaxLevelConsole`).

Additional Info:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html